# ¿Como resolver este query set?

Tags: python, django, django-models

Tengo un problema en donde quiero restar dos campos y luego actualizar un registro, que seria `cantidad - stock`, y este ultimo seria el modificado, aquí el modelo:

#### models.py:

```
class Pedido(models.Model):
    especialidad   = models.ForeignKey('Especialidad')
    fecha_entrega  = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False)
    fecha_pedido   = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,null=True, blank=True)
    bodega         = models.ForeignKey(Bodega, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    articulo = ChainedForeignKey(
        'Articulo',
        chained_field="bodega",
        chained_model_field="bodega",
        )
    cantidad       = models.CharField(max_length=999, blank=True)
    pendiente      = models.CharField(max_length=999,  null=True, blank=True)




    def __str__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.articulo, self.cantidad) 



class Articulo(models.Model):
    cod_experto = models.CharField(max_length=999, primary_key=True, blank=True)
    nombre      = models.CharField(max_length=999, blank=True)
    descripcion = models.CharField(max_length=999, blank=True, null=True)
    info_bodega = models.ForeignKey(Bodega, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    stock       = models.CharField(max_length=999, blank=True)
    extmin      = models.CharField(max_length=999, blank=True, null=True)
    extmax      = models.CharField(max_length=999, blank=True, null=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.nombre)
```

Y aquí tenemos la `query set` de `views.py`:

```
def succes(request, cod_experto):
    articulo   = Articulo.objects.filter(id=cod_experto)
    for x in cod_experto:
        cant_articulo = Articulo.objects.filter(id=x.cod_experto)
        for z in cant_articulo:            
            total = z.cantidad - x.stock
            update = Articulo.objects.values('stock').filter(id=x.cod_experto).update(stock=total)
    return redirect(reverse('usuario:index.html', kwargs={'pk': self.object.pk}))
```

Tal vez mi lógica con los modelos no es la correcta, si logran entender y formular una solución mejor a este problema se agradecería enormemente.

Answer (score 2):

En Django cuando haces un Filter, obtienes una lista de elementos. En este caso es mejor usar un [get](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-a-single-object-with-get).

Además, en tus modelos tienes Pedido.cantidad como tipo CharField, no debería ser un int?. Lo mismo para Articulo.stock .

Ahora, que es cod_experto que recibes en succes? una lista?

podrías explicar de mejor forma que quieres hacer en tu view succes? (que recibes en cod_experto?, una lista?)

Comment: estimado, tiene razon con cambiar a init, el cod_experto es la clave de Articulo, succes seria la acción de restar y modificar el stock, ya que este seria enviado a templates como un boton

Answer (score 0):

Buenas, viendo el código de la view te diría que lo formules así:

```
    def succes(request, cod_experto):

    # Acá esta de mas, porque al ser clave primaria solo va a encontrar uno así que seria un get no filter  

    articulo   = Articulo.objects.get(cod_experto=cod_experto)

    # este for estaría de mas o te falto nombrar que viene mas de un código? 
    #         for x in cod_experto:
     #       cant_articulo = Articulo.objects.get(cod=x.cod_experto)

    # este for estaría de mas tambien 

#for z in cant_articulo:  
     # por ultimo el total nuevo es el calculo, donde te falta decir cuanto se pidio, osea pasar por args la cantidad pedida o tomar del formulario esa misma cantidad#  

                total = articulo.stock- pedido.cantidad
                update = Articulo.objects.values('stock').filter(cod_experto=cod_experto).update(stock=total)
        return redirect(reverse('usuario:index.html', kwargs={'pk': self.object.pk}))
```

espero que te sirva, saludos

Comment: gracias por la respuesta, usted ha entendido la lógica al parecer, lo he cambiado como me a dicho, ahora bien el sig error me aparece: Reverse for 'succes' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['Solicitud/confirmar/(?P<pk>\\d+)/$']. lo que marca en el index: <a class="btn" btn-success" href="{% url 'usuario:succes' %}">Aprobar</a>

Comment: @DemaroCreate si has encontrado una solución, por favor publícala y [marca tu propia respuesta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) o [acepta la respuesta de otro usuario](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) que haya solucionado tu problema. Saludos.

Comment: @DemaroCreate eso quiere decir que la url que pedis necesita un argumento y vos no se lo estas pasando osea
que => 'Solicitud/confirmar/(?P<pk>\\d+)/$' la parte de pk va vacia, fiajte si en en boton la url esta asi 
{% url 'solicitud/confirmar/' 1 %} "EL NUMERO 1 de ahi es la clave que pasas"